# Centering BoxLayout with Buttons inside a GridLayout

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm working with kivy for a new project. While designing my GUI, I encountered the following problem.

I have a GridView dividing my window in three section. The top sections contains a headline, and the middle section should contain centered Buttons and Labels.

This is my current .kv file:

```
<Main>:    
rows: 3

Label:
    font_size: 25  
    text: "Some Headline"

GridLayout:
    rows: 2
    row_force_default: True
    row_default_height: 40
    col_force_default: True
    col_default_width: 200

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Button:
            text: "Button 1"
        Label:
            text: "Label 1"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Button:
            text: "Button 2"
        Label:
            text: "Label 2"
```

The resulting window looks like this

[image]

But what I want instead is that these BoxLayouts with the Bottons/Labels are centered in the window.

How can I accomplish this or what do I have to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Kivy AnchorLayout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.anchorlayout.html) with `anchor_x: 'center'` and `anchor_y: 'center'`

### [Kivy AnchorLayout » anchor_x](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.anchorlayout.html#kivy.uix.anchorlayout.AnchorLayout.anchor_x)

> ```
> anchor_x
> ```
>
> Horizontal anchor.
>
> anchor_x is an [OptionProperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.OptionProperty) and defaults to ‘center’. It
>   accepts values of ‘left’, ‘center’ or ‘right’.

### [Kivy AnchorLayout » anchor_y](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.anchorlayout.html#kivy.uix.anchorlayout.AnchorLayout.anchor_y)

> ```
> anchor_y
> ```
>
> Vertical anchor.
>
> anchor_y is an [OptionProperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.OptionProperty) and defaults to ‘center’. It
>   accepts values of ‘top’, ‘center’ or ‘bottom’.

## Example

The following example illustrates use of Kivy [AnchorLayout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.anchorlayout.html) and [Dynamic Classes](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#dynamic-classes).

### main.py

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string("""
<MiddleSection@AnchorLayout>:    # Dynamic class
    anchor_x: 'center'
    anchor_y: 'center'

    btn_txt: ''
    lbl_txt: ''

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: None, 1
        width: 200
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Button:
            text: root.btn_txt
        Label:
            text: root.lbl_txt


GridLayout:    # Root rule
    rows: 3

    Label:
        font_size: 25
        text: "Some Headline"

    GridLayout:
        rows: 2
        row_force_default: True
        row_default_height: 40

        MiddleSection:
            btn_txt: "Button 1"
            lbl_txt: "Label 1"

        MiddleSection:
            btn_txt: "Button 2"
            lbl_txt: "Label 2"


"""))
```

## Output

[image: Result]